# Differences between Pearl, Rubin, and Lewis causal models

Tags: causality

It is not totally clear to me what are the relationships between Pearl, Rubin and Lewis causal models and their philosophy/view of events. Can anybody please explain them to me?

Comment: [Related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/559240/recommendation-high-level-comparison-of-formal-causal-reasoning-approaches).

Comment: This question is perhaps too general and seems to ask for a tutorial on causality. Also related: [The counterfactual model for causation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/387805/237901).

Comment: Thanks @Alexis! @dipetkov more than a tutorial I was asking for a comparison (smith like "in Pearl we have the 3 ladder levels of causality while on other ones we don't have it because ..." but I'll try to have a look at Alexis reference first then in case I'll edit the question to be more specific

Comment: You didn't explain what you know already, so a complete stand-alone answer will have to start at the beginning and introduce causal inference and the frameworks for causal inference. By your own words that would be "more than a tutorial".